# applet deployment failure logging

Tags: logging, applet

My previously working applet is now failing.  I am using Log4J, nothing has changed, however it seems to be configured for [JDK 1.3 logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/package-summary.html).(search for META-INF/services) What could have changed that didnt or how can I override what now is?  Thank you.

```
network: Connecting http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable.class with cookie "blackbird={pos:2,size:1,load:null}; JSESSIONID=4D81E3F41BF95EE15BB2D44F54D837C8"
network: Connecting http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/commons-logging.properties with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/commons-logging.properties with cookie "blackbird={pos:2,size:1,load:null}; JSESSIONID=4D81E3F41BF95EE15BB2D44F54D837C8"
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory with cookie "blackbird={pos:2,size:1,load:null}; JSESSIONID=4D81E3F41BF95EE15BB2D44F54D837C8"
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8083/10sdaanyd/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.class with cookie "blackbird={pos:2,size:1,load:null}; JSESSIONID=4D81E3F41BF95EE15BB2D44F54D837C8"
```

Oddly it is emitting Log4J statement right up to a line `JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONData00);`   Then errors on the commons/logging objects.  I am using json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar.  Is that calling for the commons/logging?  How do I stop it as it requires that path that does not exist and I cannot create.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It needed the commons-logging.properties with these two name/value lines

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
log4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

Also, perversely, beanutils, specifically Dynabean.  I make not explicit method calls for that, and I am sure I could refactor it to eliminates.  HTH.